# Redux middleware flow

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware

I tried to understand the flow of redux, I know that middlewares wrapped around dispatch (in the applyMiddleware.js) but for the actual middleware such as thunk

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
   return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
}
   return next(action);
};
}
```

I am trying to find how the next is being called in the chain. The meaning of next function is to call the next middleware but how is it called? The previous middleware doesnt call the next function as argument but instead it call directly next(action). In short, I want to understand the actual calling chain of middleware and how the currying function do their job. I want to have clear understanding about it to have more control on writing custom middleware.

2. Once time I saw that someone wrote middleware that the next(action) is being called but after that that the middlware is still handling other stuff. How it would be possible when you pass the control to the next middleware(let say middleware 2) but still executing task in the middleware 1.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think this question is tough to answer, because you're asking about a number of things and trying to gain a general understanding. I'd suggest narrowing your question to one specific thing that you'd like to learn. Also, have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger? That may make the calling chain very clear.

Comment: I have tried debugging but still not very clear so decided to drop a question on stack. I will try once again and come back with another question which may be more specific. Thanks @ErikHermansen